# How to create FusionCharts heatmap from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, data-visualization, heatmap, fusioncharts, json-normalize

I want to show below data using FusionCharts heatmap in python:

```
[{'day_of_like': 'Monday', 'hours_of_like': 18, 'avg_of_likes': 8}, {'day_of_like': 'Monday', 'hours_of_like': 23, 'avg_of_likes': 5}]
```

But I can't find guide for that in FusionCharts site. How can I do that using python?

Answer (score 0):

- This answer uses [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to illustrate the example.
- The issue seems to be, getting the data into a useful format.
- The thing about all visualization tools is, **the data must be in the correct shape** for the tool.

  - I would use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to convert the `list` of `dict`s to a panel data form.
  - [FusionCharts Data Format](https://support.fusioncharts.com/support/solutions/articles/13000003458-fusioncharts-data-format#:%7E:text=FusionCharts%20Data%20Format%20Print&text=FusionCharts%20XT%20accepts%20XML%20or%20JSON%20data%20to%20plot%20the%20charts.&text=Data%20String%20method%20%2D%20In%20this,String%20and%20renders%20the%20chart.): *FusionCharts XT accepts XML or JSON data to plot the charts*

    - This can be done with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), which outputs a JSON string, or with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), which outputs a python `dict`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# list of dictionaries
data = [{'day_of_like': 'Monday', 'hours_of_like': 18, 'avg_of_likes': 8}, {'day_of_like': 'Monday', 'hours_of_like': 23, 'avg_of_likes': 5}]

# convert to dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# save the data to a csv if needed
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

# display(df)
  day_of_like  hours_of_like  avg_of_likes
0      Monday             18             8
1      Monday             23             5

# to json
df.to_json()

[out]:
'{"day_of_like":{"0":"Monday","1":"Monday"},"hours_of_like":{"0":18,"1":23},"avg_of_likes":{"0":8,"1":5}}'

# to dict
df.to_dict()

[out]:
{'day_of_like': {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Monday'}, 'hours_of_like': {0: 18, 1: 23}, 'avg_of_likes': {0: 8, 1: 5}}

# plot
sns.heatmap(df[['hours_of_like', 'avg_of_likes']])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data shared, looks like you have to duplicate day_of_like property, you need to either set a unique value or set a unique value for each duplicate key here is a JavaScript representation of the same in FusionCharts - http://jsfiddle.net/j3r0avhz/3/

```
  "dataset": [{
          "data": [{
              "rowid": "hl",
              "columnid": "1",
              "value": "18",
              "colorRangeLabel": "Bad"
            },
            {
              "rowid": "al",
              "columnid": "1",
              "value": "8",
              "colorRangeLabel": "Bad"
            },
          {
              "rowid": "hl",
              "columnid": "2",
              "value": "23",
              "colorRangeLabel": "Good"
            },
            {
              "rowid": "al",
              "columnid": "2",
              "value": "5",
              "colorRangeLabel": "Bad"
            }
          ]
        }]
```